# How to pass in initialized HashMap as param?

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I pass in a new HashMap in the most canonical (simplest, shortest hand) form?

```
// 1.  ?  (of course this doesn't work)
passMyHashMap(new HashMap<String, String>().put("key", "val"));

// 2.   ? (of course this doesn't work)
passMyHashMap(new HashMap<String, String>(){"key", "val"});


void passMyHashMap(HashMap<?, ?> hm) {
    // do stuff witih my hashMap
}
```

Comment: Hah, there's always "double curly" notation, but I've a feeling that if I post it as an answer, there'll be downvoters who have read somewhere that someone thinks it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @DavidWallace Post it! If you explain *clearly* what it does and why it works, then there should be no problem.

Comment: @DavidWallace Whatever, I'll take one for the team. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create it, initialize it, then pass it:

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
myMap.put("key", "val");
passMyHashMap(myMap);
```

You could use the "double curly" style that David Wallace mentions in a comment, I suppose:

```
passMyHashMap(new HashMap<String,String>(){{
    put("x", "y");
    put("a", "b");
}});
```

This essentially derives a new class from `HashMap` and sets up values in the initializer block. I don't particularly care for it (hence originally not mentioning it), but it doesn't really cause any problems per se, it's more of a style preference (it does spit out an extra `.class` file, although in most cases that's not a big deal). You could compress it all to one line if you'd like, but readability will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `put` and pass the `HashMap` into the method at the same time, because [the `put` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) doesn't return the `HashMap`.  It returns the old value from the old mapping, if it existed.

You must create the map, populate it separately, then pass it in.  It's more readable that way anyway.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "val");
passMyHashMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

## HashMap< K,V>.put

```
public **V** put(K key,V value)
```

- Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
  the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
  replaced.
- **Returns** the previous value associated with **key**, or null if there was
  no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
  previously associated null with key.)

As you can see, it does not return the type `HashMap<?, ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. What you can do is create a factory that allow you to do so.

```
public class MapFactory{
     public static Map<String, String> put(final Map<String, String> map, final String key, final String valeu){
              map.put(key, value);
              return map;
     }
}

passMyHashMap(MapFactory.put(new HashMap<String, String>(),"key", "value"));
```

Although I can't image a approach that would need such implementation, also I kinda don't like it. I would recommend you to create your map, pass the values and just then send to your method.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key","value");
passMyHashMap(map);
```